# Best way to apply a function to a slice of a 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have something like `myArray.shape == (100, 80, 2)`

I want to do something like this:
`numpy.apply_along_axis(function, 0, myArray)` 
where `function` uses both items on the `axis=2` axis of myArray, but I know `numpy.apply_along_axis` only works for 1D slices.

My question is: Is there a generic way to go about acting a function to 2D slices without having to use a loop or does it depend on how I have `function` defined? And if so, what would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Is it possible to use `numpy.apply_along_axis` to act on one 1D slice and `zip` each element in the other slice to each element in the first slice somehow? Would it help to restructure `myArray`?

Note: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470582/efficient-way-to-apply-function-to-each-2d-slice-of-3d-numpy-array) did not answer my question, so please don't mark as duplicate.

Comment: "does it depend on how I have function defined?"... Yes, very much.

Comment: `apply_along` uses loops.  It's nkt entirely clear what you trying to do.  Show us with an explicit loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define a simple function that takes a 2d array, and returns a scalar

```
In [54]: def foo(x):
    ...:     assert(x.ndim == 2)
    ...:     return x.mean()
    ...: 
In [55]: X = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
```

It's not entirely clear how you want to iterate on the 3d array, but let's assume it's on the first axis.  The straight forward list comprehension approach is:

```
In [56]: [foo(x) for x in X]
Out[56]: [5.5, 17.5]
```

`vectorize` normally feeds scalars to the function, but the newer versions have `signature` parameter that allow us to use it as:

```
In [58]: f = np.vectorize(foo, signature='(n,m)->()')
In [59]: f(X)
Out[59]: array([ 5.5, 17.5])
```

The original vectorize does not promise any speed up, and the signature version is even a bit slower.

`apply_along_axis` just hides iteration.  Even though it only operates on 1d arrays, we can use it with a bit of reshaping:

```
In [62]: np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: foo(x.reshape(3,4)), 1, X.reshape(2,-1))
Out[62]: array([ 5.5, 17.5])
```

As long as you are only iterating on one axis, the list comprehension approach is both fastest and easiest.