# Setup sliding windows as columns (IM2COL from MATLAB) in multi-dimensional array - Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

Currently, I have a 4d array, say,

```py
arr = np.arange(48).reshape((2,2,3,4))
```

I want to apply a function that takes a 2d array as input to each 2d array sliced from `arr`. I have searched and read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470582/efficient-way-to-apply-function-to-each-2d-slice-of-3d-numpy-array), which is exactly what I want.

The function I'm using is `im2col_sliding_broadcasting()` which I get from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109068/implement-matlabs-im2col-sliding-in-python/30110497#30110497). It takes a 2d array and list of 2 elements as input and returns a 2d array. In my case: it takes `3x4` 2d array and a list `[2, 2]` and returns `4x6` 2d array.

I considered using `apply_along_axis()` but [as said](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) it only accepts `1d` function as parameter. I can't apply `im2col` function this way.

I want an output that has the shape as `2x2x4x6`. Surely I can achieve this with for loop, but I heard that it's too time expensive:

```py
import numpy as np

def im2col_sliding_broadcasting(A, BSZ, stepsize=1):
    # source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30110497/10666066
    # Parameters
    M, N = A.shape
    col_extent = N - BSZ[1] + 1
    row_extent = M - BSZ[0] + 1

    # Get Starting block indices
    start_idx = np.arange(BSZ[0])[:, None]*N + np.arange(BSZ[1])

    # Get offsetted indices across the height and width of input array
    offset_idx = np.arange(row_extent)[:, None]*N + np.arange(col_extent)

    # Get all actual indices & index into input array for final output
    return np.take(A, start_idx.ravel()[:, None] + offset_idx.ravel()[::stepsize])

arr = np.arange(48).reshape((2,2,3,4))
output = np.empty([2,2,4,6])

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        temp = im2col_sliding_broadcasting(arr[i, j], [2,2])
        output[i, j] = temp
```

Since my `arr` in fact is a `10000x3x64x64` array. So my question is: Is there another way to do this more efficiently ?

Comment: `apply_along_axis` even where is works is not a time saver.  It just makes iterating over the other dimensions easier.

Comment: @hpaulj yeah I know, but I can't even use `apply_along_axis` in this case =)))

Comment: So you aren't loosing anything by not being able to use it.

Comment: @hpaulj It's what pop up in my mind before I do looping. And then I realize it's too slow and I can't find a way to transform arr into something that can work with it

Comment: **approach #2** in your linked answer can be extended to work with the whole (2,2,3,4) array.  **#3** also, though I'm less familiar with its internals.  These strided methods initially create a `view`, which has a low memory footprint.  But it's easy to trigger a copy, which could end up giving a memory error.

Comment: @hpaulj I don't understand too much about stride, but I'm gonna try it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Use `scikit-image's view_as_windows` : `from skimage.util import view_as_windows as viewW; output = viewW(arr,(1,1,2,2))[...,0,0,:,:].transpose(0,1,2,4,3,5).reshape(2,2,4,6)`. If you need a view output, skip the last reshaping. More info - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064

Comment: @Divakar though I'm still confusing a bit, it works. Thank you so much. Please post this as an answer so I will marked this as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windows. [More info on use of `as_strided` based `view_as_windows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/).

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

W1,W2 = 2,2 # window size

# create sliding windows along last two axes1
w = view_as_windows(arr,(1,1,W1,W2))[...,0,0,:,:]

# Merge the window axes (tha last two axes) and 
# merge the axes along which those windows were created (3rd and 4th axes)
outshp = arr.shape[:-2] + (W1*W2,) + ((arr.shape[-2]-W1+1)*(arr.shape[-1]-W2+1),)
out = w.transpose(0,1,4,5,2,3).reshape(outshp)
```

The last step forces a copy. So, skip it if possible.

Comment: Since each 2d array in my output is a group of columns, I would use `reshape(2,2,6,4)` and then `np.einsum('ijkl->ijlk', out)` to get the final result. And yeah, I have to create a copy, but I'm gonna delete it later so it doesn't bother me. Again, thank you.